# Programmatically make a Header item 'hot' or 'selected'

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm using a Win32 Header. I want to make it so that the header item I click on stays 'selected' or looks selected until I press another one. I want to avoid disabling it for aesthetic reasons.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a visual indication on the header only, or on the entire list?

Comment: Just a visual indication on the clicked header item (not the whole header control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this header is part of a listview, you can provide a visual clue with [ListView_SetSelectedColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775109(VS.85).aspx)